using Dynamodb keywords in DMS table mapping json
I have a requirement to use dynamodb reserved keyword as attribute name on the DDB side. So I am using "expression-attribute-names" in the mapping json for my DMS task.
Note: This is a migration project from SQL Server to DDB.
Edit1: "target-attribute-name" is mandatory and it is not a valid mapping json. Without that, I will not be able to create a DMS task.
I tried using "exclude-columns" to exclude attirbute "#d", but still no success.
                    {
                        "target-attribute-name": "#d",
                        "expression-attribute-names": {"#d":"Data"},
                        "attribute-type": "scalar",
                        "attribute-sub-type": "string",
                        "value": "${Data}"
                    }

This one fixed the issue but the problem is now for 1 column on the SQL side, I have two attributes are migrated "#d" and "Data" with same value.
I achieved my requirement of having the column mapped to an attribute called "data" , but I get an additional duplicate attribute "#d" which is redundant and not needed.
How to overcome this. Please help
